# Laravel 5.1 LTS, TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, laravel

I have a strange problem when requesting some external images in L5.1. I have a script which requests some images (GET), if ill return local images (from the assets folder) - everything works fine. But if i return some pictures returned from an Controller the next request (POST) always gives me:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:
```

It seems that its loosing the session, but when ill manually check the Token (and compare it to the value in the meta content) - its the same value.

My CSRF Token is added to the index.html in the header:

```
<meta content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" name="csrf-token" />
```

And the code for requesting the images is:

```
public function get_image($filename) {

    $path = storage_path() . '/app/uploads/article/full/' . $filename;

    if(!File::exists($path)) abort(404);

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: ummmm, try `{{ csrf_token() }}` instead of what you have. It should be working.

Comment: That makes no difference ;)

Comment: then update your question and post all related code, otherwise, there is no way to know what's happening.

Comment: If i use {!! !!} or {{ }} then result should be the same.  Not sure which code is missing, because not sure whats happening (maybe its in returning the image?)

Comment: make sure your controller is using the `auth` middleware, and if you're sending an ajax request, make sure you're sending the csrf token along with it

Comment: Ive tried both (and outside too) - the problem is still there even when ill exclude the route from the csrf middleware. Now i copied all the images into the assets folder, and its no problem anymore - it seems there is only a problem requesting images with that piece of code.

Comment: I'm unclear. Is it the image request that's throwing the exception?

Comment: No, every image gets display normally. BUT the next (POST) request always returns an exception.